# Duplicate letters being posted in setState React & socketIO

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm creating an editable textarea in react and websocket. When one person types "a", it should post on the other person's textarea as well. The problem is when person 1 types "a", person 2 gets "aa". I've narrowed it down to how the list variable works and it being str.substring(0, start) and str.substring(stop, str.length) but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
const [testlist, setList] = useState([]);

socket.on('edit-text', ([start, stop, data, id]) => { 
    let str;
    setList(list => {
       str = list[id];
       list[data[4]][0] = str.substring(0, start) + data + str.substring(stop, str.length);
       return [...list];
    });
});
```

Comment: your ```socket.on("edit-text)"``` is inside a ```useEffect``` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that.